# Unable to detect cam module in raspberry pi 3 b+

Tags: camera, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I have my cam module connected and have also tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade but the pi is unable to detect the cam module.

On executing this command : `vcgencmd get_camera`

**outputs**: supported = 0, detected = 0

Why does it say supported = 0? Is there something wrong with the operating system?

Comment: Which OS is running? Did you enable the camera in 'raspi-config' or the 'Raspberry Pi Configuration' utility on the desktop?

Comment: It is running raspbian stretch. There is no option for camera in the raspi-config

Comment: There *is*:  option 5 (interfacing) / P1 (camera)

Comment: BTW: `supported=0` means that the camera is *not* enabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run `sudo raspi-config` and enable the camera from there before you can use it.  The main menu should have an "Interfacing Options" submenu (probably #5).  From there the option to enable the camera should be clear.

You will need to reboot after that.

What this does is add/enable (uncommented, ie. with no leading `#`):

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

within `/boot/config.txt`.  If the camera is not enabled after you reboot, check that file to make sure.  Those should not be commented out (meaning there should be no `#` at the beginning of the line).

Comment: Wow that made the trick. I've raspbian bullseye so there is no option to enable/disable the camera from raspi-config. Adding manually "start_x" in the /boot/config.txt file solved my problem. Maybe someone with a new camera could add "camera_auto_detect=1"